# This 'while' loop countdown with sleep doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm having some issues with a `bash` script, but I don't know why. The script is meant to convert the input (in minutes) to seconds and then start counting down until it reaches zero, at which point the script should stop.

When I add a `sleep 1` in between, it doesn't count down anymore; why is this happening?

Code:

```
if [ -z $1 ];
then
     read NUMBER
else NUMBER=$1
fi
SECONDS=$(( NUMBER * 60 ))

while [ $SECONDS -gt 0 ]
do
      sleep 1
      SECONDS=$(( SECONDS - 1))
      echo $SECONDS remaining
done

echo end
```

Comment: Just a word of warning: sleep doesn't guarantee an exact time of sleeping and can be quite inaccurate.

Comment: Please modify the tile of this question to include the key fact that the loop (ab)uses a system variable.

Comment: @MontyHarder If they'd known that, they wouldn't have had the problem in the first place. The answer shouldn't be in the question/title.

Comment: @JackAidley And even if the `sleep` time were totally accurate, the loop would still get out of time because it doesn't account for the shell processing time etc. (Amusingly, using the shell built-in `$SECONDS` as intended would work around that!)

Comment: This is a great reason not to capitalize variables in scripts. ALL_CAPS should be reserved for environment and special variables.

Answer (score 20):

`SECONDS` is a variable that's used internally by Bash, and the way this variable works is interfering with your script's decrement action.  If you use a different variable name (like `SECS` or `seconds`) then it works fine.  E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -z $1 ];
then
     read NUMBER
else NUMBER=$1
fi

SECS=$(( NUMBER * 60 ))

while [ $SECS -gt 0 ]
do
      sleep 1
      SECS=$(( SECS - 1 ))
      echo $SECS remaining
done

echo end
```

The Bash man page describes the behavior you're seeing with the `SECONDS` variable:

```
SECONDS
       Each time this parameter is referenced, it expands to the number of sec-
       onds since shell invocation.  If a value is  assigned  to  SECONDS,  the
       value returned upon subsequent references is the number of seconds since
       the assignment plus the value assigned.  The number of seconds at  shell
       invocation  and  the  current time are always determined by querying the
       system clock.  If SECONDS is unset, it  loses  its  special  properties,
       even if it is subsequently reset.
```

Since each reference of `SECONDS` was one second after the previous assignment, the value returned was that second plus the first value assigned (before the `while` loop).  So, in effect, each time through the loop the decrement was being undone.

(also, I added a space between `1` and `))` to be consistent with your previous usage)

Answer (score 10):

As [@SottoVoce said](/a/749714), `$SECONDS` is a special variable in bash and other Korn-like shells.

In bash and ksh (not zsh), unsetting the variable as with `unset -v SECONDS` removes its special meaning, but in general, you don't want to use all-uppercase variable names in shell scripts other than for environment ones.

There are a few other issues in your script:

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env bash
>
> if [ -z $1 ];
> ```

That doesn't make sense.  You forgot the quotes around `$1`, so that's subject to split+glob and empty-removal, so if `$1` is empty or unset, that becomes the same as `[ -z ]` which is the same as `[ -n -z ]` to check whether `-z` is a non-empty string, so it will return true then. And if `$1` is `foo bar` or `*`, that will cause some error. To check whether some arguments are passed or not, you compare the number of arguments (`$#`) with 0:

```
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ] # standard
if (( $# == 0 )) # Korn-like shells
```

> ```
> then
>      read NUMBER
> ```

Beware `read` does some stripping of `$IFS` characters and some backslash processing, which is probably just fine for a number, but in general to read a line of input, it's:

```
IFS= read -r minutes
```

> ```
> else NUMBER=$1
> fi
>
> SECONDS=$(( NUMBER * 60 ))
> ```

[Using unsanitised data in arithmetic expressions is a command injection vulnerability in bash and other Korn-like shells](/q/172103).

You'd want something like:

```
case $minutes in
  ("" | *[!0123456789]*) echo>&2 invalid number of minutes; exit 1;;
esac
(( seconds = minutes * 60 ))
```

To make sure you get a sequence of digits.

> ```
> while [ $SECONDS -gt 0 ]
> ```

bash treats numbers with leading 0s as octal in arithmetic expressions, but not in `[`'s numeric comparison expressions where they're always considered as decimal, so don't mix and match.

```
while (( seconds > 0 ))
```

> ```
> do
>       sleep 1
>       SECONDS=$(( SECONDS - 1))
>       echo $SECONDS remaining
> done
> ```

You could also do:

```
for (( seconds = minutes * 60; seconds > 0; seconds-- )); do
  echo "$seconds seconds remaining"
  sleep 1
done
```

But note that running commands also takes some time, running `sleep 1` 1000 times is likely to take at least 1001 seconds as forking a process and running `sleep` in it would take at least one microsecond, and if you run more commands in your loop, that will drift even more.

To fix that, you could actually use the `$SECONDS` special variable, but not in bash where it is currently [broken](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2016-02/msg00160.html) and where you can't make it floating point. In zsh instead:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
(( $# )) || vared -cp 'Enter the number of minutes: ' 1
[[ $1 = <-> ]] || {
  print -u2 Invalid number.
  exit 1
}

(( seconds = 60 * $1 ))
typeset -F SECONDS=0
for (( tick = 1; tick <= seconds; tick++ )); do
  printf '%g seconds remaining\n' seconds-SECONDS
  (( (delay = tick - SECONDS) <= 0 )) || sleep $delay
done
```